# Excel formula to count multiple possible combinations in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Newbie-ish with Excel here. I'm trying to keep things simple for long term ease of use since most at my job don't know much of anything with Excel or anything with VBA.

I'm looking to have a formula count cells containing up to 4 different codes  (TRM2-TRM5) out of 32 possible codes. However, the cell these combinations are entered in is not required to be in any specific order.

Such as:

`B1` (TRM2, R2, TRM3)

`B2` (TRM2, PN1, DC5, TRM4)

`B3` (PN1, IPA5c, HW2, TRM5)

`B4` (PN1, HW2, R2)

The desired result of the formula is a count of 3

I don't need to count the individual number of times the TRM codes appear. Just the number of cells they appear in a range (such as `B1:B99`).

I've tried `COUNTIFS` but quickly discovered I'd have to have a `COUNTIFS` for each possible combination of the 4 codes.

So far the simplest way is to use multiple instances of conditional formatting that highlights the cells that contain one of the four codes and do a visual count. All the examples I've read don't have multiple values in one cell so I'm not sure how to tackle it.

For those that are curious, the purpose is error reporting for issues missed in an audit.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are looking for `TRM2`, `TRM3`, `TRM4` and `TRM5`. Could `TRM1` or `TRM6` of `TRM23` (or any other number) be among the codes listed?

Answer (score 1):

Given your example, you can do this with a helper column.

Either hard code an array constant with the codes to find, or enter them in separate cells someplace.  I did the latter and named that range `theCodes`.

Use this **array** formula in the helper column:

```
C1: =MIN(FIND(theCodes,B1&CONCAT(theCodes)))<LEN(B1)
```

and fill down as far as needed

This will return `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on whether any of the codes are present in the cell.

Then, a simple `COUNTIF` will count all the `TRUE`'s

```
 D1: =COUNTIF($C:$C,TRUE)
```

[image]

**NOTE:**  To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

Comment: If we know all codes to be counted contain TRM, then I would simplify the helper column to return 1 if it contains TRM,  0 if it doesn't and name it "has TRM"and then sum it.

Comment: @spioter Yes.  It is often the case that we can devise different parameters for a question that will result in a simpler solution.